# Real affine variety of $d$ orthonormal vectors in $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, orthonormal, affine-schemes

I'm interested in the affine variety
$$
V = \left\{ \, A\in \mathbb R^{d\,\times\, n} \, \middle| \, A\,A^T = I \, \right\} \subseteq \mathbb R^{d\, \times\, n},
$$
where $n\ge d$ and $I$ is the $d\times d$ unit matrix. This is the set of real $d\times n$ matrices with orthonormal rows, so another way to look at this is the configuration space of $d$ orthonormal vectors in $\mathbb R^n$.

For $n=d$ we have $V=\operatorname{O}(n,\mathbb R)$, so $V$ is not irreducible since it splits in two components where $\det(A)=1$ and $\det(A)=-1$, respectively. I'm guessing that this decomposition is already the decomposition of $V$ into irreducible components for $d=n$, but I'm not sure how to show that or where to look for a reference.

For $n>d$ I would guess that $V$ is irreducible, but I don't know how to figure out whether that is true.

I'd appreciate it, if anybody could provide insight or references on this problem.

Comment: You can think of this as $O(n) / O(n-d)$, where $O(n-d)$ is embedding in $O(n)$ by putting the matrix in the lower right corner of a matrix and filling in the upper left with the $d \times d$ identity. This is called something like "the frame bundle" (perhaps "the orthogonal frame bundle"?), and comes up in discussions of Grassmannians, etc. (or so I recall from grad school). Not sure this helps, but might at least get you pointed to the right literature.

Comment: smooth and connected implies irreducible; homogeneous spaces of connected groups are smooth and connected (this remark is irresponsible and one should replace $\mathbb R$ with $\mathbb C$ to make it safer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This variety $V$ is called *Stiefel manifold*. See

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiefel_manifold

There you find a lot of properties, in particular that $V$ is connected for $d<n$ as you guess. The essential point here is that while you cannot move continuously an ortonormal basis into another if they give opposite orientations, when $d<n$ you can make the move jumping outside of the $d$-plane they generate. Consider a $d$-frame $\{u_1,\dots,u_d\}$. Since $d<n$ there is some line ortogonal to $L=L[u_1,\dots,u_d]$, generated by a unitary vector $w$, and you can rotate $u_d$ in the plane $\Pi=L[u_d,w]$ to get $-u_d$, say you have a continuous path of unitary vectors $\gamma(t)\in\Pi$ with $\gamma(0)=u_d,\gamma(1)=-u_d$ (here we jump off $L$). In the end, 
$$
\varGamma(t)=\{u_1,\dots,u_{d-1},\gamma(t)\}
$$
is a path in $V$ connecting $\{u_1,\dots,u_d\}$ to $\{u_1,\dots,-u_d\}$, two frames with opposite orientation. Thus all frames generating the same $d$-plane are connected by a path. Then one must connect different $d$-planes, which is just to say that the Grassmanian $G$ of $d$-planes in $\mathbb R^n$ is connected. This is also classical. For instance

[Fundamental groups of Grassmann and Stiefel manifolds](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69533/fundamental-groups-of-grassmann-and-stiefel-manifolds)

Next for irreducibility, yes, smooth and connected implies irreducibility in the real case.
This is just *the identity principle:* if a polynomial $f$ does not vanish on $V$, smooth and connected, $\{f=0\}\cap V$ has empty interior. It follows that if neither $f$ nor $g$ vanish, we have $V\setminus\{fg=0\}=(V\setminus\{f=0\})\cap (V\setminus\{g=0\})$, and an intersection of two dense open sets is open dense, hence not empty (we don't need Baire here). It is good to remark that the problem is the converse: irreducible smooth does not implies connectedness (non-singular real cubics provide examples).

Comment: I managed to check irreducibility in a different way: Cutting off the last $n-d$ rows of orthogonal $n\times n$ matrices, we get a surjection $SO(n)\to V$ for $n>d$, and $SO(n)$ is an irreducible real affine variety. Now I'm wondering if the complex Stiefel manifold is also an irreducible real affine variety. It isn't a complex variety since the equations involve complex conjugates…

Comment: Yes, this works very well! Concerning the complex Stiefel manifold, it is connected, hence irreducible, as a complex algebraic variety. Now, it has an _underlying real manifold structure_. Examples of this: complex line is real plane, complex projective line is real sphere... Real dimension is topological dimension, twice the complex dimension. Thus, the complex Stiefel manifold is a real algebraic manifold, also connected, hence real irreducible.